# Не работает кнопка Full screen video в Webview

Tags: android, webview

MainActivity

```
package ru.kinobe.kinobe;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.ActivityInfo;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.appindexing.Action;
import com.google.android.gms.appindexing.AppIndex;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private WebView webView;
    private FrameLayout customViewContainer;
    private WebChromeClient.CustomViewCallback customViewCallback;
    private View mCustomView;
    private myWebChromeClient mWebChromeClient;
    private myWebViewClient mWebViewClient;
    private FrameLayout mTargetView;
    private FrameLayout mContentView;
    private WebChromeClient.CustomViewCallback mCustomViewCallback;

    /**
     * ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
     * See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
     */
    private GoogleApiClient client;


    /**
     * Called when the activity is first created.
     */
    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }


    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        outState.putString("key", "value");
    }


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            String string = savedInstanceState.getString("key");
        }

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        customViewContainer = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.customViewContainer);
        webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);

        mWebViewClient = new myWebViewClient();
        webView.setWebViewClient(mWebViewClient);

        mWebChromeClient = new myWebChromeClient();
        webView.setWebChromeClient(mWebChromeClient);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);
        webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(false);
        webView.getSettings().setSaveFormData(true);
        final WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_CACHE_ELSE_NETWORK);


        final Activity activity = this;
        webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
            public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress) {
                // Activities and WebViews measure progress with different scales.
                // The progress meter will automatically disappear when we reach 100%
                activity.setProgress(progress * 1000);
            }
        });
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
                Toast.makeText(activity, "Нет интернет соединения! Перезапустите приложение. ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                webView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }
        });
        webView.loadUrl("http://kinobe.ru");
        webView.setBackgroundColor(0x00000000);

        // ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
        // See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
        client = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this).addApi(AppIndex.API).build();
    }


    public boolean inCustomView() {
        return (mCustomView != null);
    }

    public void hideCustomView() {
        mWebChromeClient.onHideCustomView();
    }


    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();    //To change body of overridden methods use File | Settings | File Templates.
        webView.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();    //To change body of overridden methods use File | Settings | File Templates.
        webView.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();    //To change body of overridden methods use File | Settings | File Templates.
        // ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
        // See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
        Action viewAction = Action.newAction(
                Action.TYPE_VIEW, // TODO: choose an action type.
                "Main Page", // TODO: Define a title for the content shown.
                // TODO: If you have web page content that matches this app activity's content,
                // make sure this auto-generated web page URL is correct.
                // Otherwise, set the URL to null.
                Uri.parse("http://host/path"),
                // TODO: Make sure this auto-generated app deep link URI is correct.
                Uri.parse("android-app://ru.kinobe.kinobe/http/host/path")
        );
        AppIndex.AppIndexApi.end(client, viewAction);
        if (inCustomView()) {
            hideCustomView();
        }
        // ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
        // See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
        client.disconnect();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {

            if (inCustomView()) {
                hideCustomView();
                return true;
            }

            if ((mCustomView == null) && webView.canGoBack()) {
                webView.goBack();
                return true;
            }
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        // ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
        // See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
        client.connect();
        Action viewAction = Action.newAction(
                Action.TYPE_VIEW, // TODO: choose an action type.
                "Main Page", // TODO: Define a title for the content shown.
                // TODO: If you have web page content that matches this app activity's content,
                // make sure this auto-generated web page URL is correct.
                // Otherwise, set the URL to null.
                Uri.parse("http://host/path"),
                // TODO: Make sure this auto-generated app deep link URI is correct.
                Uri.parse("android-app://ru.kinobe.kinobe/http/host/path")
        );
        AppIndex.AppIndexApi.start(client, viewAction);
    }

    class myWebChromeClient extends WebChromeClient {
        private Bitmap mDefaultVideoPoster;
        private View mVideoProgressView;

        @Override
        public void onShowCustomView(View view, int requestedOrientation, CustomViewCallback callback) {
            onShowCustomView(view, callback);    //To change body of overridden methods use File | Settings | File Templates.
        }

        @Override
        public void onShowCustomView(View view, CustomViewCallback callback) {

            mCustomView = view;
            // if a view already exists then immediately terminate the new one
            if (mCustomView != null) {
                callback.onCustomViewHidden();
                return;
            }
            mCustomView = view;
            webView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            customViewContainer.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            customViewContainer.addView(view);
            customViewCallback = callback;
        }

        @Override
        public View getVideoLoadingProgressView() {

            if (mVideoProgressView == null) {
                LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(MainActivity.this);
                mVideoProgressView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.video_progress, null);
            }
            return mVideoProgressView;
        }

        @Override
        public void onHideCustomView() {
            super.onHideCustomView();    //To change body of overridden methods use File | Settings | File Templates.
            if (mCustomView == null)
                return;
            mCustomView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            mCustomView = null;
            webView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            customViewContainer.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            // Hide the custom view.
            mCustomView.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            // Remove the custom view from its container.
            customViewContainer.removeView(mCustomView);
            customViewCallback.onCustomViewHidden();

            mCustomView = null;
        }
    }

    class myWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            return super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, url);    //To change body of overridden methods use File | Settings | File Templates.
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: давайте я отдебажу все ваше приложение, выкладывайте и остальные классы тоже, нужно весь ваш код. Да и все остальные проекты выкладывайте тоже

Answer (score 2):

```
 setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        customViewContainer = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.customViewContainer);
        webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);

        mWebViewClient = new myWebViewClient();
        webView.setWebViewClient(mWebViewClient);

        mWebChromeClient = new myWebChromeClient();
        webView.setWebChromeClient(mWebChromeClient);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);
        webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(false);
        webView.getSettings().setSaveFormData(true);
        final WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_CACHE_ELSE_NETWORK);
```

У вас тут дублирование

Comment: И это должно пофиксить проблему?

Comment: Вряд ли, скорей должно способствовать появлению классным комментариям

Comment: Я вообще-то задал адекватный вопрос. Мне кажется, что это заведомо не решит проблему, но я не уверен. Поэтому я и спросил, считаете ли вы, что это должно решить проблему, или этот ответ - не более, чем просто комментарий к коду автора?